# How to get the first element from an array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to get the first element from an array using `<li> {{i [0] .name}} </li>` but I get the error that Cannot read property '`name`' of undefined. Here is my complete code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul v-for="(i, index) in btnGroup" :key="index">
      <li>{{ i[0].name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      btnGroup: [{ name: "Alex" }, { name: "Robert" }, { name: "Fabiano" }],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: If you only want to get the first element, shouldn't it be `btnGroup[0]`? And since you're only accessing a single item you don't need to use `v-for`

Comment: `i` represents the current object in your loop, it looks like `{ name: "Alex" }` which is not an array to be accessed via `i[0].name`

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ test[0] }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      btnGroup: [
        { name: "Alex", age: 12 },
        { name: "Robert", age: 23 },
        { name: "Fabiano", age: 30 },
      ],
    };
  },

  computed: {
    test: function () {
      return this.btnGroup.map((i, index) => {
        return i.name + i.age;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
{{ i.name }}
```

instead of `{{ i[0].name }}`

Or you can use like this

```
{{ btnGroup[index].name }}
```

Overall, i is element of object array

Answer (score 0):

use `<li>{{ i.name }}</li>` instead of `<li>{{ i[0].name }}</li>`

( `i` here is no more an array but an item of the array at position `index`. )